# Is it ever illegal to change a lock so as to exclude your landlord access?

Tags: england-and-wales

Most leases say you can never do it without permission but permission wouldn't be unreasonably withheld but if you ever do it then you absolutely must give LL notification and issue of the new key.

Are these terms valid or overridden by the common law covenant doctrine of exclusive possession? I've read that if you change them back to originals upon leaving then you can never be forbidden as an AST to do that in England.

Comment: What if the landlord needs to do emergency repairs when the tenant is absent?

Comment: @Rick The landlord can call a locksmith in case of emergency.

Comment: An emergency requires an immediate response, waiting for a locksmith will only delay matters.

Comment: I do not see what added details or clarity is needed here, the question is quite clear. IMO this should not be closed on that ground.

Comment: I having a hard time concieving an actual emergency that is most appropriately dealt with by a landlord, and not some professional emergency response team.

Comment: @Rick Firefighters and police are equipped to force a door. Repair crews might also be able to force a door, because typical doors aren’t made to stand up to power tools.

Comment: @Jasen  A water leak or overflowing faucet  likely to damage plaster or wallboard, but not dangerous to others or to property i shut oiff promptly. An apparently unattended infant. A small fire which can be dealt with by a hand extinguisher. A window open to a rainstorm, likely to cause property damage but not harm to any person.

Comment: @DavidSiegel if the tennants are expecting you to provide that assistance they will not have changed the locks.

Comment: Wow, unexpected turn in reading this thread. Right up until t the end my i intended comment was to praise and side with Jasen but you then also make excellent points David.

Comment: Yes @Jasen: but, it's arguably the landlords property and they have an interest in preventing irreparably damage to it, so perhaps it isn't entirely up to the tenant?

Comment: In general however notwithstanding those caveats I mostly side with Jasen on the matter still. If damage is caused by negligence of the tenant then hopefully the LL has insurance and can pursue tenant for damages?

Answer (score 1):

The common law covenants of "quiet enjoyment" and exclusive possession never excluded access in a *bona fide* emergency, and a landlord would be entitled, and perhaps **required**, to break a door or window open if needed to gain access in the face of an emergency such as a gas leak, where others are potentially endangered and time is of the essence.

That said, a valid and reasonable contract may specify this as the parties please, unless  **specific** law overrides this. For example a local landlord/tenant law could require that the landlord be given access (such as a key) Aside from such laws, the lease can forbid changing locks, permit it only with permission, or permit it freely (perhaps requiring that the landlord be given a key). Any of those provisions would be lawful in the absence of a specific law to the contrary. The lease could also specify when the landlord is to have access, and how much notice. But a provision denying access in a true emergency is probably not valid.

Comment: in a true emergency the landlord is the wrong person to take action, unless they are on an apropriate emergency response team.

Comment: The people taking the action might reasonably ask the landlord to let them in.

Comment: they should be asking the tennant. and if denied they are justified to break down the door or take other apropriate action.

Comment: Yes @Jasha I agree completely.

Comment: Honestly David I feel as though your answer rather largely just dodges the question: yes, we may agree that in bona fide exceptional/emergency circumstances, the landlord would probably be entitled to enter without permission, possibly by breaking in if their key didn't work. But the question is whether it's ever not legally permitted, irrespective of what a contract says, to exclude them under normal circumstances by changing and withholding the key. They may always still be legally entitled to break in but then much less tempted to abuse their

Comment: keyed access casually as it would come at the cost of damaging their own property.

Comment: (in England and Wales).

Comment: Raising another question: if tenant withholds the key, and the landlord wants access for a lawful purpose and so breaks down the door, is the tenant liable for the damage to the door?